# How to Add or Minus a Value from a set Time in LUA

Tags: linux, variables, lua, global-variables

What I have is a value pulled from a slider somewhere else and it will be between 0 and 100.

I stuck this value in sliderValue and turned it into minutes (i think) in the minutes variable.
if the original value is 50 then no change happens to the time but if it's 51 then I want 2 minutes to be added to the time and same for the reverse, 49 is minus 2 minutes.

Always 2 minutes (2, 4 , 6, 8 and so on) hence the minutes variable.
All I simply want to do is add or take the minutes from my  "8:05" time.

Thoughts ?

```
function tempFunc()
local currentDate = os.date("*t");
local startSource = fibaro:getSourceTrigger()
local sliderValue = fibaro:getGlobalValue("MorningTime")

local minutes = ((sliderValue - 50) x 120)

if (( fibaro:getGlobalValue("MorningScene") == "On"  and  
     ((currentDate.wday == 2 or 
     currentDate.wday == 3 or 
     currentDate.wday == 4 or 
     currentDate.wday == 5 or 
     currentDate.wday == 6) and 
     string.format("%02d", currentDate.hour) .. ":" .. string.format("%02d", currentDate.min) == "08:05") ))
     then
     fibaro:call(5, "setArmed", "1");
  end
 setTimeout(tempFunc, 60*1000)
end

if (sourceTrigger["type"] == "autostart") then
  tempFunc()
 else

 local currentDate = os.date("*t");
 local startSource = fibaro:getSourceTrigger()
 if
  (fibaro:getGlobalValue("MorningScene") == "On" and 
  (currentDate.wday == 2 or 
   currentDate.wday == 3 or 
   currentDate.wday == 4 or 
   currentDate.wday == 5 or 
   currentDate.wday == 6))
  then
    fibaro:call(5, "setArmed", "1")
 end

end
```

Comment: Why did you tag java ?

Comment: I find a lot of java code and ways can be used within Lua too

Comment: @NowBeginsLife: That's not the purpose of tags. Tags exist to describe the nature of your question. Your question does not include Java, so it's not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to pass `currentDate` back to `os.time`, just add your value for `minutes` to the value in `currentDate.min`, according to the Lua manual:

> The values in these fields do not need to be inside their valid ranges. For instance, if `sec` is -10, it means -10 seconds from the time specified by the other fields; if `hour` is 1000, it means +1000 hours from the time specified by the other fields.

So:

```
-- Fixed calculation - esp. use * for multiplaction, rather than x!
local minutes = ((sliderValue - 50) * 2)
currentDate.min = currentDate.min + minutes

-- Later, use the 'new value' in currentDate
local newTimestamp = os.time(currentDate) -- do something with newTimestamp
```

I strongly recommend reading the manual entries to [os.time()](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-os.time) and [os.date()](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-os.date) to understand the concepts behind date calculations in Lua.